# Patrones de diseño C++ (GoF)

Tags: c++, patrones-de-diseño, ingenieria-del-software, arquitectura-de-software, reflexión

Aprendí a programar de forma autodidacta y después de multiples proyectos fracasados me dí cuenta de una cosa. Estaba intentando crear (sin quererlo) mis propios patrones de diseño sin caer en la cuenta de que la mayoría de los patrones que pueden solucionar mis problemas y desarrollar software de forma eficiente ya estaban creados.
He estado estudiando dos libros:

> **UML y patrones de diseño**

de *Craig Larman*

> **Patterns Design**

de los *GoF*

Mientras que el primero utiliza Java para los ejemplos, el segundo utiliza C++. 
A mi me gusta más C++. Pero....
En Java he podido observar que puedes elegir que objetos instanciar (por ejemplo de una Fabrica) a través de una cadena que puedes recoger, bien sea de una variable de entorno o de un registro de clases. Lo cual suprime estructuras de control condicionales a la hora de poder elegir que instanciar en tiempo de ejecución.
Sin embargo en C++ no se si eso es posible y me pregunto si a la hora de tomar decisiones sobre las clases a instanciar en tiempo de ejecución han de hacerse mediante condicionales .
Disculpen si no me expreso bien. Me gustaría usar palabras como *Programación reflexiva* o *Lenguaje estático* pero me temo que mis conocimientos aùn son excasos.

**Concretando: ¿Es posible elegir que clases instanciar en tiempo de ejecución sin tener que someter cada elección a una estructura condicional en C++?**

*Mi intuición me guía a referenciar funciones en un hash y que se ejecute esa función según la clave. El único modo de evitar condicionales que conozco es usar estructuras de datos (pero vengo de JavaScript, nada que ver)*

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un pequeño ejemplo con código? a veces es mejor que cualquier explicación para entender bien lo que se pregunta

Comment: Te sugiero comenzar por el [patrón factoria](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Method_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o))

Comment: Puede ser un tema interesante ... pero también es **demasiado amplio** sin un caso concreto del que partir. De momento, voto por cerrarla.

Comment: "*En Java he podido observar que puedes elegir que objetos instanciar a través de una cadena*" esto es conocido como [Reflexión](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) y no todos los lenguajes disponen de mecanismos de reflexión. Como has podido observar [tag:c++] no es uno de ellos.

Answer (score 2):

> Lo cual suprime estructuras de control condicionales a la hora de poder elegir que instanciar en tiempo de ejecución

Esa afirmación es totalmente falsa. Que no tengas que programar tu la condición no implica que no exista... esas cadenas tienen que compararse contra algo para que el proceso pueda determinar qué instancia debe crear.

La magia, en este caso, se encuentra detrás de la cortina... tu no la ves, pero está ahí.

> ¿Es posible elegir que clases instanciar en tiempo de ejecución sin tener que someter cada elección a una estructura condicional en C++?

No, pero eso es así en C++ y en cualquier otro lenguaje. Ya lo he explicado en el punto anterior

> Mi intuición me guía a referenciar funciones en un hash y que se ejecute esa función según la clave. El único modo de evitar condicionales que conozco es usar estructuras de datos (pero vengo de JavaScript, nada que ver)

¿Y con eso evitas condicionales? **NO**

El hash, nuevamente, tendrás que compararlo contra otros hashes para determinar las coincidencias.

Otra cosa sería decir que usando hashes se consiguen mejores tiempos de ejecución que usando cadenas... pero las comparaciones, aunque odiosas, son imprescindibles.

Puedes, de hecho, hacer un ejercicio práctico: Intenta programar un sistema como el que comentas pero sin hacer uso de la magia de los metadatos y la reflexión. Como no quieres usar condicionales tendrás que evitar el uso de mapas, árboles y listas... ya que para elegir un elemento en concreto tendrás que hacer comparaciones (o las haces tu o las hace el contenedor... pero son comparaciones al fin y al cabo).

Comment: Buena respuesta.

Comment: Pero aún así si me gustaría saber si se puede usar algún tipo de estructura.. La pregunta es si existe la forma de hacerlo. De poder almacenar alguna referencia a la clase en alguna estructura y de poder y poder usarla a través de la estructura. No solo para evitar un codigo más engorroso. Si no porque si la estructura es un array, acceder a ella por indices no tendría condicionales pues accede directamente por la direccón del array + el indice. ,según tengo entendido.

Answer (score 1):

Los lenguajes [java](/questions/tagged/java) y [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tienen un ancestro común pero parten de filosofías distintas.

#### Uno de los lemas base de Java es "*Funciona en cualquier sitio*".

Para que Java cumpla con el lema "*Funciona en cualquier sitio*" tuvo que hacer sacrificios: Es un lenguaje semicompilado, la salida del compilador Java es un [*bytecode*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) que después deberá ser interpretada (o acabada de compilar) por la [máquina virtual](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_virtual_Java).

Esta estrategia tiene ventajas e inconvenientes, como ventaja podemos decir que tu código Java funcionará en cualquier sistema (siempre que disponga de máquina virtual) sin modificación alguna, pero en algunos casos podría ser sensiblemente más lento que un lenguaje compilado (aunque compensa con optimizaciones en tiempo de ejecución), otra de las características intrínsecas de los lenguajes semicompilados es que deben guardar mucha información de los tipos en el *bytecode*, lo que hace que los ejecutables ocupen más y sean más suceptibles a la [ingeniería inversa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingenier%C3%ADa_inversa) (por lo que a veces se requiere [ofuscar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ofuscaci%C3%B3n) el *bytecode*).

Es la información de los tipos guardada en el *bytecode* lo que permite a Java usar [reflexión](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29).

#### Uno de los lemas base de C++ es "*No pagues por lo que no usas*".

Para que C++ cumpla con el lema "*No pagues por lo que no usas*" tuvo que hacer sacrificios: Es un lenguaje compilado, la salida del compilador C++ es un ejecutable nativo del sistema en que se compila.

Esta estrategia tiene ventajas e inconvenientes, como ventaja podemos decir que tu código C++ funcionará en el sistema directamente sin necesidad de comprobaciones adicionales ni postproceso alguno, pero una vez compilado es invariable así que todas las optimizaciones se hacen durante la compilación (que suele ser costosa), otra de las características intrínsecas de los lenguajes compilados es que debido a las agresivas optimizaciones que se hacen en tiempo de compilación, el binario compilado elimina muchas de las cosas no usadas, entre ellas la información [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information).

Es la ausencia de información de tipos en el binario compilado lo que impide a C++ usar reflexión.

---

> ¿Es posible elegir que clases instanciar en tiempo de ejecución sin tener que someter cada elección a una estructura condicional en C++?

No. Incluso usando los más esotéricos y arcanos trucos de C++ al final, [como señala eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/293329/2742), la decisión se tendrá que hacer mediante una estructura condicional, Java lo hará en tiempo de ejecución y C++ lo hará en tiempo de compilación.

En C++ puedes usar plantillas, supón que tenemos dos clases que no son instanciables más que desde una factoría:

```
class Hola
{
    Hola() = default;
//  ^^^^^^ <-- Constructor privado, ¡esta clase no se puede instanciar!
    template <typename tipo_t, typename ... parametros_t>
    friend tipo_t Factoria(parametros_t ...);
//  ^^^^^^ <-- La función 'Factoria' puede acceder a la zona privada de 'Hola'
};

class Mundo
{
    Mundo(int) {};
//  ^^^^^ <-- Constructor privado, ¡esta clase no se puede instanciar!
    template <typename tipo_t, typename ... parametros_t>
    friend tipo_t Factoria(parametros_t ...);
//  ^^^^^^ <-- La función 'Factoria' puede acceder a la zona privada de 'Mundo'
};

template <typename tipo_t, typename ... parametros_t>
tipo_t Factoria(parametros_t ... argumentos)
{
    return {argumentos ...};
}
```

Podrás instanciar estas clases por su *nombre*:

```
int main()
{
    // 'Factoria' Puede instanciar 'Hola' y 'Mundo' sin problemas.
    auto h = Factoria<Hola>();
    auto m = Factoria<Mundo>(0);
    // 'Factoria' Puede instanciar cualquier cosa Ô_ô
    auto i = Factoria<int>();

    std::cout << &h << ' ' << &m << ' ' << i;

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[TIO](https://tio.run/##vVFNa8MwDD1Hv0Iw2BzYQs9NmuPYZb@hCNttDfEHtnwYIb89s7N2622wwzDYkt6T9GTJEF7OUq7rg3FyykrjYHziqMmOAHKilPDNTwQzNPUVLR5Q6RPliXtoWNswEZcs/gjakdXIJvgjP@N3oOs6DBSLydGnI4/QnKLRTl2p@EqSfTQk7lk1re1h6W8q3rNTvsrYDGEctzgv/6Xhb01@K44Uz9lqxz61dbSoOUeH80@4skr/BaAMjJaMExuTMnu8lF3cag91O6Mocr8we49tXzaKXUGhSaz2e@kz4zDg46XeT@VUx1b8KmJXuq7rJw)</kbd>. Aunque no parezca haber estructuras de control condicionales en el código, internamente el compilador las ha escrito: "***Si `tipo_t` de la plantilla es** `Hola` **entonces** crea `Hola`*, ***Si `tipo_t` de la plantilla es** `Mundo` **entonces** crea `Mundo`*, …".