# ¿Porqué al definir un vector de tamaño N se pueden asignar valores a posiciones mayores sin que haya error?

Tags: c++

Si tengo el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *vector = new int[10];
    vector[20] = 100;
    cout<<vector[0]<<endl;
    cout<<vector[20];
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

La salida es:

> 134416161
>   100
>   Presione una tecla para continuar

¿No se supone que el compilador debe marcar error al asignar valor a una posición del vector que excede su tamaño, por ejemplo el **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** de java?

Comment: creo que `vector` es solo un apuntador hacía la posición en memoria de `new int[10]`.

Comment: Med, me gusta tu foto de perfil :)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no tengo una foto decente, así que aplico la vieja confiable y uso una portada de disco que me guste :p. Muchas gracias por resolver mi duda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > ¿Porqué al definir un vector de tamaño N se pueden asignar valores a posiciones mayores sin que haya error?

Hay la posibilidad de que haya una [falla de segmentación](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) en tiempo de ejecución y esto hará que el programa deje de funcionar al instante.

Cuando esta sentencia se ejecute:

```c
vector[20] = 100;
```

Hay la probabilidad que se intente escribir el número `100` en un registro de memoria que le corresponda al sistema operativo y esto provocará que el programa deje de funcionar, debido a que, se estaría accediendo a una dirección de memoria que al programa no le pertenece (a esto se lo denomina falla de segmentación).

Esto quiere decir, que al momento de desbordar el vector, lo único que se logra es arriesgar al programa que aborte de manera inmediata. Sin embargo, este no es el único problema que podría pasar.

**¿Qué pasaría si la dirección de memoria calculada con la expresión `vector[20]` le pertenece en realidad al programa actual?**

Sería fatal. No ocurrirá falla de segmentación, porque estarías intentando escribir en una dirección de memoria propia del programa, sin embargo, esa ubicación podría tener un dato almacenado y por culpa del desbordamiento, se perdería la información que se tenga en el registro (en pocas palabras, habría sobreescritura de información). Esto en la práctica puede ser difícil de depurar, **¡así que mucho cuidado!**.

**Ejemplo del posible error:**

```c
#include <iostream>

int main(void) 
{
    int* v = new int[10];
    v[9999] = 100;
    std::cout << v[9999];
    return 0;
}
```

He ejecutado el código de arriba en Windows y básicamente el programa dejó de funcionar, debido a que, ocurrió una falla de segmentación.

Al parecer esta sentencia:

```c
v[9999] = 100;
```

Está tratando de sobreescribir un registro de memoria que no le pertenece al programa y esto ocasiona que en ningún momento se imprima en pantalla el número deseado.

**Conclusión:**

Aunque no te dé un error de sintaxis por parte del compilador, tendrás problemas en tiempo de ejecución. El programa puede que deje de funcionar dependiendo si la dirección de memoria calculada no le pertenece al programa.

Comment: "*Esto dependerá del compilador. Puede que dé un error de sintaxis o no*". ¿Tienes algún ejemplo de algún compilador que de error de sintaxis en ese caso?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Buena pregunta. Me pusiste a investigar y la verdad no encontré ningún compilador en la cual dé un error en tiempo de compilación. Edito la respuesta para no generar confusión.

Comment: xD Ya me parecía raro, Dave.

Answer (score 3):

En resumen: C++ no hace ninguna validación de acceso a elementos fuera de los límites de un "arreglo" https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/accessing-array-bounds-ccpp/

A detalle: tu variable `vector` en realidad está apuntando a una posición en memoria. El uso de `vector[X]` es [azúcar sintáctico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329296/c-why-accessing-dynamic-array-is-used-without-the-asterisk-operator) para referenciarse al espacio en memoria a X bloques de distancia de donde inicia `vector`.

Answer (score 3):

- ¿En qué casa vives?
- En la cuarta.
- Si vives en la cuarta ¿Cómo es posible que esté llamando al timbre de la octava?

[image]

- Que yo viva en cuarta casa no borra la existencia de la octava.

---

> ¿No se supone que el compilador debe marcar error al asignar valor a una posición del vector que excede su tamaño, por ejemplo el **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** de java?

Java y C++ son lenguajes distintos con filosofías distintas. Mientras que la filosofía de Java es "*funciona en cualquier sitio*" la de C++ es "*no pagues por lo que no usas*" (un poco más de detalles sobre ese tema [en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/293318/patrones-de-dise%C3%B1o-c-gof/293342#293342)).

C++ considera que la responsabilidad de comprobar los límites de colecciones de datos recae en quien programa; así que asume que cualquier acceso a un elemento de una colección de datos será siempre correcto y compilador evita generar código para hacer esas comprobaciones… en contrapartida si se accede mal a los datos, el resultado es imprevisible.

Java considera la responsabilidad de comprobar los límites de colecciones de datos como suya; por lo que no se fía de ninguno de los accesos a elementos de una colección de datos y generará código para comprobar cada uno de ellos… si se accede mal a los datos, el resultado será una excepción.

Estas diferencias hacen que en general C++ sea un lenguaje más rápido, ya que "*se permite*" generar código que da menos pasos para ciertas tareas, mientras que Java en general será algo más lento porque "*se preocupa*" por dar más pasos para hacer ciertas tareas.